# Substitute a function in an algebraic expression

Tags: calc

I have this algebraic expression

```
    x                       L                                             L 
    ⌠                       ⌠                                             ⌠  s
    ⎮ s*(L - x) f(s) ds   x ⎮ (L - s) f(s) ds                           Y ⎮ ---- ds
    ⌡                       ⌡                     L                       ⌡ f(s)
    0                       x                     ⌠ ⎛    s⎞               0 
1:  ------------------- + ------------------- = X ⎮ ⎜1 - -⎟ * f(s) ds + -----------
             L                     L              ⌡ ⎝    L⎠                  L
                                                  0
```

and I would like to substitute different expressions, e.g. `sin(2 s)` or `(L -s ) s / 4`,
for `f(s)` and finally evaluate the integrals (it's as simple as pressing `=`) — but I don't know how to apply the requested substitution at once (I know how I could, painstakingly, change all the occurrences of `f(s)` one by one)

Comment: Does the menu item `Calc -> Algebra -> Manipulation -> Make substitution` not work? It just works for me for the algebraic expression `int(s*(L-x)*f(s)/L,s,0,x)+int((L-s)*f(s)/L,s,x,L)` with `sin(s)` substituted for `f(s)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Calc manual on [`calc-substitute`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#index-a-b).

Quote:

> The ‘a b’ (‘calc-substitute’) [‘subst’] command substitutes all
> occurrences of some variable or sub-expression of an expression with a
> new sub-expression.  For example, substituting ‘sin(x)’ with ‘cos(y)’ in
> ‘2 sin(x)<sup>2</sup> + x sin(x) + sin(2 x)’ produces ‘2 cos(y)<sup>2</sup> + x cos(y) +
> sin(2 x)’.  Note that this is a purely structural substitution; the lone
> ‘x’ and the ‘sin(2 x)’ stayed the same because they did not look like
> ‘sin(x)’.  *Note Rewrite Rules::, for a more general method for doing
> substitutions.
>
> The ‘a b’ command normally prompts for two formulas, the old one and
> the new one.  If you enter a blank line for the first prompt, all three
> arguments are taken from the stack (new, then old, then target
> expression).  If you type an old formula but then enter a blank line for
> the new one, the new formula is taken from top-of-stack and the target
> from second-to-top.  If you answer both prompts, the target is taken
> from top-of-stack as usual.